# Why is Go json.Marshal rejecting these struct tags? What is proper syntax for json tags?

Tags: json, go, struct, tags, marshalling

I am trying to use json.Marshal but it refuses to accept my struct tags.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the source code for "marshal.go"

https://play.golang.org/p/eFe03_89Ly9

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string `json: "name"`
    Age  int    `json: "age"`
}

func main() {
    p := Person{Name: "Alice", Age: 29}
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    fmt.Println("JSON = ", string(bytes))
}
```

I get these error messages from "go vet marshal.go"

```
./marshal.go:9: struct field tag `json: "name"` not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag value
./marshal.go:10: struct field tag `json: "age"` not compatible with reflect.StructTag.Get: bad syntax for struct tag value
```

I get this output when I run the program.

```
% ./marshal
JSON =  {"Name":"Alice","Age":29}
```

Notice the field names match the Go structure and ignore the json tags.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing the space after the colon i.e. `\`json:"name"\``

Comment: The valid syntax is *exactly* what is described in [the documentation for encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal). It is not forgiving of differences in whitespace etc.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: `go vet` is your friend.

Answer (score 81):

Oh my goodness!  I just figured it out.  There is no space allowed between `json:` and the field name `"name"`.

The "go vet" error message (`"bad syntax"`) is remarkably unhelpful.

The following code works.  Can you see the difference?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

func main() {
    p := Person{Name: "Alice", Age: 29}
    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    fmt.Println("JSON = ", string(bytes))
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had something similar with the space in:  ```json:"containers, omitempty"` ```

Comment: You saved infinite amount of time of all people that starting with Go

Comment: 2 years into Go and still making this mistake lol

Comment: Thanks bro, I struggled this simple issue for 3 days :)

Comment: Seriously. Wow!! So silly